# How to display the boot screen notebook on a monitor?

Tags: windows-7, display, bootloader

The monitor of my notebook is broken and I want to install Arch-Linux on it. I have no problem to display the windows screen on an external monitor, but it doesn't show the initial screen where we choose the boot options. Is it possible to configure my computer through Windows for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your BIOS is probably set to skip the boot screen.

Click **Start** -> Right-Click **Computer** -> **Properties** -> **Advanced** System Settings ->**Advanced** Tab

Click on **Settings** in *Startup and Recovery Section*

See if there is a Check in Time to display list of operating systems (you can set the time in seconds)